# Rendering JSON in React with varying structure of the key/value pairs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a question about how to render the json return from API calls where the result set varies in construct.  So, what if you have 3 API calls and each one has a different structure...let's say one contains first_name and last_name, but the second contains something different like date_time and email address, and the third contains none of these but contains an array of users?

How would one write a map function to iterate over a state object that contains the data and this state object contains many different structures and you can render the key and the value?

First call

```
{
   "first_name": "foo",
   "last_name": "bar"
}
```

Second call

```
{
   "email": "foo@bar.com"
   "date": "some date"
}
```

Third call

```
{
   "first_name": "foo"
   "last_name": "bar"
   "users": [
       "user1",
       "user2",
       "user3"
   ]
}
```

Each api call would return the data into `this.state.searchData` of course.  Looking for a DRY, elegant method to handle any structure to render the key/value pairs without writing 3 different methods to iterate over the results.  Thanks!

Comment: This will depend on how you are going to render your results...Have no idea about that...Example..How your `users` array should be render

Comment: Basically I would like to render out something simple at first just in a table or divs... showing the key "first name", etc and then the value.  I would probably render out the users in a <ul> <li> structure and maybe the rest in just divs, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will fulfill your requirement.

```
    <div>
        {
            Object.entries(this.state.searchData).map(([key, value]) => (
                <ul>
                    <li>{key}</li>
                    <li>{
                        (
                            Array.isArray(value)) && (
                            value.map(element => {
                                <li>{element}</li>
                            })
                        ) || (<li>{value}</li>)
                    }</li>
                </ul>
            )
            )
        }
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably would do something like this to start:

```
return (
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Key</th>
                <th>Value</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => (
             <tr>
                 <td>{key}</td>
                 <td>
                     {Array.isArray(value) ? (
                     <ul>
                         {value.map(v => <li>{v}</li>}
                     </ul>
                     ) : value}
                 </td>
             </tr>
        )}
        </tbody>
    </table>
);
```

Comment: This is a great example as well.  Thank you both!  Much appreciated.